# Scalar function as a part of computed column

Tags: sql-server, function, calculated-columns

I am using SQL Server 2012. I want to create a table with a computed column. This column is a sum of columns in this table, but I need to multiply the sum by a VAT rate from VAT table to get a gross value including the tax. VAT values are inserted into the VAT table every month and stored in column Stawka as smallint (in English it means "Rate").
Values to table Prąd also are inserted every month so I need to use current VAT rate from column Stawka in VAT table.

So if the tax rate (columnn Stawka in VAT table) is currently 23%, it's simple math:
(Y+Z) + 23% * (Y+Z) =( Y+Z) * (1 + 0.23) = (Y+Z) * 1.23 where Y+Z is a sum of decimal columns before the last one in table Prąd.

Row example from table Prąd. Below in last column (computed column) it is only sum of 0.2661 + 0.2103. So as above, first I need to sum 0.2103 and 0.2661 and then to multiply the sum by 1.23:

```
ID  Data    Rok Kwartał Miesiąc Dzień   Jednostka   Odczyt  Zużycie Energia elektryczna czynna  Opłata dystrybucyjna zmienna Stawka jednostkowa energii
1 2015-01-01 2015   1     1      1        kWh        300      20         0.2661                    0.2103                            0.4764
```

I cannot hard-code value 1.23 because the VAT rate can change so I've decided to create a VAT table but I don't know how to use these values in column Stawka inside computed column.

I tried to use some tips I found here and use a scalar function to get the current VAT value and concatenate but it seems I cannot use it just as a part of whole calculation. Some code below:

Table with computed column I'm trying to create(Error invalid column "Stawka" pops up while creating the table):

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Prąd
(
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
Data DATE NOT NULL,
Rok AS YEAR(Data) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
Kwartał AS DATEPART(q,Data) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
Miesiąc AS MONTH(Data) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
Dzień AS DAY(Data) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
Jednostka VARCHAR (5) NULL,
Odczyt SMALLINT NOT NULL,
Zużycie SMALLINT NOT NULL,
[Energia elektryczna czynna] DECIMAL (9,4) NULL,
[Opłata dystrybucyjna zmienna] DECIMAL (9,4) NULL,
[Stawka jednostkowa energii] AS CAST (([Energia elektryczna czynna] + [Opłata dystrybucyjna zmienna])*('1.' + dbo.fnVAT(ID)) AS DECIMAL (9,4)) PERSISTED NOT NULL
)
```

VAT table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.VAT
(
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
Data DATE NOT NULL,
Stawka SMALLINT NOT NULL,
);
```

Scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnVAT (@VAT SMALLINT)

RETURNS SMALLINT

AS BEGIN

SELECT @VAT = Stawka FROM VAT AS V JOIN Prąd AS P ON V.ID = P.ID

RETURN @VAT

END
```

Comment: The parameter is called @VAT, but you don't use it for anything, except for returning the value? And the Stawka seems to be a column in the VAT table, not the one where you're adding the column?

Comment: Just a guess, but should the parameter be ID from Prad and the join from the function removed?

Comment: Well, it's my first function ever written in SQL so the logic might be an issue here. Yes, @VAT parameter only returns a value from column Stawka in VAT table, not the one I am adding the computed column.What I need in other words is to get the tax value (column Stawka) from VAT table to make a gross value of one of the columns used in computed column. Definitely I cannot do that by simple select statement.I used a join to make sure that appriopriate value of VAT (for current month) will be used in computed column in table Prąd (so the unit cost for current month is computed correctly)

Comment: @JamesZ Was my comment any helpful in explaining the idea of what I'm trying to do ? Maybe someone else could help ?
I suppose I could omit multiplication in the computed column and just use a trigger after insert, but I hoped I could use a funciotn here to learn something new.

Comment: At least I haven't figured out how you calculate the VAT from the values. Could you edit the question to have a concrete example of the row of the table where you need the calculated column and how that value is calculated from VAT table.

Comment: And if you create an example into SQL Fiddle that would be even better

Comment: @JamesZ I've edited the question, please let me know if it's more lucid now.

Comment: a view is not an option? with a view using a join you would avoid the use of the function.

Comment: Well a trigger after insert is an option as well I think, I was just curious if there is a way to use values from other tables in computed columns and after viewing a few answers here it is possible. But I don't know how to correctly use a function here in computed column and I am not even sure whether my logic in the function is ok because I've never written one before. And which solution would the best ?

Comment: I would have more expected that the function would be passed a *date* and would then locate, say, the latest row in `VAT` which has a `Data` value that is earlier than the passed in date, and return the `Stawka` from that row. Does that not make sense? (Give or take what you do when the dates are exactly equal)

Comment: Or pass an ID as @JamesZ suggested and get last `Stawka` value. Always first will be inserted `Stawka` for current month (every 1st of month) and after that values into Prąd table. So something like this?:
`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnVAT] (@ID INT)

RETURNS SMALLINT

AS BEGIN

DECLARE
@VAT SMALLINT

SELECT @ID = MAX(ID) FROM dbo.VAT
SELECT @VAT = Stawka FROM dbo.VAT WHERE ID = @ID

RETURN @VAT

END

Comment: But the problem now, is while creating table Prąd there is a column not deterministic error. When I use `with schemabinding` in function and then try to create table with such computed column there is another error:
"computed column cannot be persisted because the column does user or system data access"
It's going to be much more difficult than expected so I guess I'll have to stay with trigger...

Comment: EDIT: Or not... "A computed column cannot be the target of an INSERT or UPDATE statement."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the VAT depends on the contents of the other table, I don't think it's possible to create that column as persisted. This means that every time you select that column, the scalar function will be called separately for every row in the select. This can be really bad for performance and I can't really recommend it, but if you want to do it, this is the way to do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnVAT (@DATE date)    
RETURNS decimal(3,2)    
AS BEGIN
    declare @VAT smallint

    SELECT top 1 @VAT = VAT FROM VAT where Date <= @DATE order by DATE desc 

    RETURN 1 + 0.01 * @VAT
END;

alter table Prad add VAT AS (Value1 + Value2) * dbo.fnVAT(Date)
```

My example was made using this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Prad
    ([ID] int, [Date] date, [Value1] DECIMAL (9,4), [Value2] DECIMAL (9,4))
```

Since I thought it would be a lot easier for me to not use the Polish(?) column names.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77369/1)

Like you said, you could do this also in a trigger, which should be a lot better performance wise since then the fetch is only done once, and since VAT doesn't really change that often it might be the best idea.

Comment: As I wrote in last comment, a trigger is not an option here anymore because: "A computed column cannot be the target of an INSERT or UPDATE statement." so your solution seems to be the only way.

Comment: @kkris77 If you're handling it with a trigger then it must be just a normal column